# iOS iPod API - get actual song file

Tags: ios, api, file, ipod

In my app I wand to present the media picker, to let the user choose 1 song, and then get it's actual MP3 (or any other format as long as its playable by other iOS devices) file.

How Can that be accomplished? 
How can I actually create an object with the songs file?

Comment: Why does this look like you're trying to find a way to get mp3 files without permission?

Comment: I will be getting the user's permission...

Comment: As a matter of fact I am not trying to do anything illegal here (for change).

Comment: @IddoGino, DiMono might be on to something. This sounds like a rejection waiting to happen. If you plan to publish this on the app store, Apple will almost certainly reject. Of course, if the file stays local and ONLY every local, then you are okay. However, if you are going to try to distribute this file, it will not get accepted. However, if your purpose is not to distribute it, I am curious on your purpose. Media Picker is available offline, so why do you need to actually claim the file?

Comment: what i am trying to do is stream the file to another device so it will play on there, but the file won't be saved on the device after it is played. Is there any other way of doing that without being rejected?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why everyone is saying so much bs about getting rejected from the app store. I'll give you a quick rundown on how to get started.

-Present the Media Picker to open the user's iPod:

```
MPMediaPickerController *pickerController = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
pickerController.prompt = NSLocalizedString(@"Choose Song", NULL);
pickerController.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
pickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
[pickerController release];
```

-Wait till the user chooses a song and get the callback in the mediaPicker delegate:

```
   - (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    MPMediaItem *theChosenSong = [[mediaItemCollection items]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *songTitle = [theChosenSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *artist = [theChosenSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

   //then just get the assetURL
    NSURL *assetURL = [theChosenSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset  *songAsset  = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];

  //Now that you have this, either just write the asset (or part of) to disk, access the asset directly, send the written asset to another device etc

}
```